# Are there systems that are put on the cluster nodes and find each other by using UDP broadcast?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, broadcast, hierarchical-clustering

I want to automate the compilation of a list of IP addresses on which I can run the MPI program. I.e. get a list of all available servers automatically.

Are there cluster management systems that are put on the cluster nodes and find each other by using UDP broadcast? And then IP addresses which found are used to run MPI-daemons and my MPI-programs.

OS: Linux

Comment: This question is probably too general for this site since it's asking for people's opinions on software, but as a general answer, what you probably are describing is a job scheduler (like SLURM for instance). I'd imagine that this is probably overkill for you. Why do you need to generate this list every time? Can you not just generate this list once on your machine?

Comment: [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) (a cluster monitoring tool) uses UDP multicast to communicate system parameters between the nodes being monitored. The gexec execution environment (seems to no longer be in development) can then utilise Ganglia to build cluster node lists for use in MPI hostfiles.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev  Thanks, but UDP **multicast** must know list of IP addresses of servers on wich are installed cluster's monitoring tool. But are there any monitoring tools, which use UDP **broadcast** to find each other?

Comment: UDP multicast needs to have all nodes configured with the same **IP multicast group**. Multicast groups in IP are usually implemented using local network broadcasts.